# Writing to txt file in UTF-8 - Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, text-processing

My django application gets document from user, created some report about it, and write to `txt` file. The interesting problem is that everything works very well on my Mac OS. But on Windows, it can not read some letters, converts it to symbols like `é™`, `ä±`. Here are my codes:

`views.py`:

```
def result(request):
    last_uploaded = OriginalDocument.objects.latest('id')
    original = open(str(last_uploaded.document), 'r')
    original_words = original.read().lower().split()
    words_count = len(original_words)
    open_original = open(str(last_uploaded.document), "r")
    read_original = open_original.read()
    characters_count = len(read_original)
    report_fives = open("static/report_documents/" + str(last_uploaded.student_name) + 
    "-" + str(last_uploaded.document_title) + "-5.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")
    # Path to the documents with which original doc is comparing
    path = 'static/other_documents/doc*.txt'
    files = glob.glob(path)
    #endregion

    rows, found_count, fives_count, rounded_percentage_five, percentage_for_chart_five, fives_for_report, founded_docs_for_report = search_by_five(last_uploaded, 5, original_words, report_fives, files)


    context = {
        ...
    }

    return render(request, 'result.html', context)
```

`report txt file`:

```
['universitetindé™', 'té™hsili', 'alä±ram.', 'mé™n'] was found in static/other_documents\doc1.txt.
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're calling `open()` on a file without specifying the encoding. As noted in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), the default encoding is platform dependent. That's probably why you're seeing different results in Windows and MacOS.

Assuming that the file itself was actually encoded in UTF-8, just specify that when reading the file:

```
original = open(str(last_uploaded.document), 'r', encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: man, after adding this attribute to that line, the result disappears :(

Comment: even report doc file not opening because of unknown characters error by ms word.

Comment: I've found problem ! Thank you so much !